# can't refer my external library package as a single entry in config.json

Tags: javascript, spfx, webpack

I created a few libraries that I use in webapps and the webpack in the cosumer app is able to resolve the lib root when added to the externals in webpack and not bundle anything that comes from that package being it the main.js that reexports the other packages or with deep imports that exports each file without importing the whole lib.

What I can't figure is that in spfx when I build the solution if I don't put each submodule as a an entry in the config.json the webpack from spfx will bundle it. Which is what I am trying to avoid.

Here is what is set in my config.json and the devdeps in my spfx package.json so I can use the lib locally.

config.json

```
//...
"externals": {
    "assets": "https://mycdn/assets/dist/main.js",
    "design": "https://mycdn/design/dist/main.js",
    "vendor": "https://mycdn/vendor/dist/main.js",
    "design/dist/styles/main-normalize": "https://mycdn/design/dist/styles/main-normalize",
    "design/dist/components/footer.style-normalize": "https://mycdn/design/dist/components/footer.style-normalize",
    "design/dist/components/button.style-normalize": "https://mycdn/design/dist/components/button.style-normalize",
    "design/dist/components/tooltip.style-normalize": "https://mycdn/design/dist/components/tooltip.style-normalize",
    "design/dist/components/footer": "https://mycdn/design/dist/components/footer",
    "vendor/dist/cqfill.iife": "https://mycdn/vendor/dist/cqfill.iife.js"
  },
//...
```

package.json

```
//...
  "devDependencies": {
    "design": "file:../../design",
    "assets": "file:../../assets",
    "vendor": "file:../../vendor",
   }
//...
```

The above works just fine but as the solution grows or if one of the packages uses many of the subcomponents it will get really hard to manage this config.json and to keep managing files.

How I wanted it to work was like:

```
//...
"externals": {
    "assets": "https://mycdn/assets/dist/main.js", //or https://mycdn/assets/dist/
    "design": "https://mycdn/design/dist/main.js", //or https://mycdn/assets/dist/
    "vendor": "https://mycdn/vendor/dist/main.js" //or https://mycdn/assets/dist/
  },
//...
```

And it would resolve all files from that directory and it would not bundle it to the solution. Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

I tried to create a multipart library but that is not very straight forward.
I know this can be solved by creating the lib the same way fp-ts in built, for example I can do:
[image]

```
//I can do the 3 imports above they all work and they all give the correct bundle sizes.
import * as fpTs from 'fp-ts'
import { option } from 'fp-ts'
import * as Option from 'fp-ts/Option'
```

If anyone knows a template for authoring libs this way I would really appreciate and if it works I can also accept that as an anwser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is actually the way webpack map external dependencies, with webpack you can pass it as a function and build an array / object an place it in the config for all your submodules either they are used or not and that is how I solved it for me.

```
//in my case this works but you need the 'webpack-manifest-plugin' plugin as well
//this will place in the external all multipart or submodules you have in your bundle. so when doing 'minimal-module-webpack/some_module.js' webpack know it is an external and which file to point to
const minimalModuleWebpackManifest = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('../minimal-module-webpack/dist/manifest.json')); // read and parse the manifest.

const objReduce = (acc, cv) => ({ ['./' + cv[0].split('.')[0]]: './' + cv[1], ...acc })

const mapToExternal = (o) => Object.entries(o).reduce(objReduce, {})
module.exports = {
//...
externals: mapToExternal(minimalModuleWebpackManifest),
//...
};
```

you can do the same with spfx but then you need to modify your config.json at build time or just add all references before hand.